# Call to undefined function Intervention\Image\Gd\imagecreatefromjpeg()

Tags: php, laravel, docker, gd, php.ini

Запускаю Laravel:5.4 + Voyager в Docker. Всё вроде работает, но при загрузке изображения через админ панель Voyager вылетает ошибка:

> Call to undefined function Intervention\Image\Gd\imagecreatefromjpeg()

При чём gd установлен и включен

[image: конфигурация Dockerfile]

[image: Ошибка]

[image: phpinfo()]

Comment: сто процентов проблема с php, попробуйте переустановить либо php, либо gd. Эта ошибка к Ларавелу отношения не имеет.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение в изменении конфигурации Dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng12-dev \
    libxpm-dev \
    libvpx-dev \
&& docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    --with-freetype-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
    --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
    --with-xpm-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
    --with-vpx-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
&& docker-php-ext-install gd
```